# How to decode BleManager.read response?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, decode, react-native-ble-manager

I am trying to do this:

```
const readGlucose = (id, serviceUUID, charasteristicUUID) => {
BleManager.read(id, serviceUUID, charasteristicUUID)
  .then(res => {
    console.log('read response', res); // [229, 7, 7, 27, 12, 19, 0]
    if (res) {
      const buffer = Buffer.from(res);
      const data = buffer.toString();
      console.log('data', data); // �♀‼
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('read err', error);
  });
```

};

but the response persists encoded...

**Revelant Infos:**

serviceUUID: 1808 => Glucose Service

characteristUUID: 2A08 => Date Time Characteristic

**PS:**

Im getting the same encoded response to anyone characterist that i tried